# How can I have different code for different Targets in XCode for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an application with several different Targets defined. I know that I can use preprocessor directives to have different sections of code for different targets, but how do the naming conventions work? For instance, if I have two Targets called "Smith" and "Smith Plus" how do these translate?

```
#if (Smith)
#elif (Smith Plus)
#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have it right.

In your project settings, when you click on a target you will see a tab for 'build settings'. Under there search for preprocessor macros.  For your smith target, add a the preprocessor macro "SMITH=1". Do the same for your smith plus target (SMITH_PLUS=1).

Then, in your code, you just use the like you illustrated yourself:

```
#if SMITH
    // do something
#elif SMITH_PLUS
   // do something else
#endif
```

Comment: For future reference you need to select "All" then look under "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 - Preprocessing".